# how to add a closing braces for each row in notepadd++

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have a file opening with notepadd++, it is shown as follows:

```
insert into agent_sales values(61,39858
insert into agent_sales values(101,5786
insert into agent_sales values(40,32230
insert into agent_sales values(122,39873
insert into agent_sales values(183,40588
insert into agent_sales values(141,47961
```

now i want to add a closing brace to each row, as the position of last character of each row is different, is it possible to do it using regex expression in notepad++ ?

Comment: Find what: `$`, Replace with: `\)`, Search Mode. Regular Expression

Comment: I find it odd that you actually _tagged_ this with 'regex' so you knew that that would be the solution, and yet you couldn't just google around for the regex basics...

Comment: @wp78de it is cool,thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or `Search > Replace`
2. Select `Regular Expression` down left
3. Enter `$` (representing the end-of-line in regex) to search
4. Replace it by `\)` (has to be escaped because we're using regex)
5. Click on `Replace All`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + H

In Find What ,

```
(insert into agent_sales values\(\d+,\d+)
```

In Replace ,

```
\1\)
```

Use Search Mode as Regular Expressions.

Then Press Replace All

Comment: i got it, \1 match the whole string, then add a closing brace,